# Using make to compile code in c in terminal on Mac

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, cc

I'm trying to learn to program in C and I'm getting used to compiling the code after writing it. I'm actually using K&R 2nd edition to start off and they use 'cc' to compile. I originally started using Zed Shaw's Learn C The Hard Way but I've stopped because I haven't heard many good things about it. Zed Shaw's way was to use 'make' to compile code, at least in the beginning.

Is there any technical difference between using 'make' and using 'cc' that I should be concerned about right now?

Comment: `make` requires you to write a `Makefile` for your project, which is basically a format for directions telling the compiler and linker what to do. `cc` is just a C compiler.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You are probably aware that `make` has many default settings that can be used without a `Makefile`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I actually wasn't aware of that. I've never tried running `make` on a project that didn't have a `Makefile`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Zed Shaw discussed a Makefile a little bit in the book before I quit it, but I don't understand what it is and I don't have one for the simple programs I am doing with K&R's book. Make still seems to work though. I just don't want to create a bad habit right at the start by doing that if i shouldn't.

Comment: Once you get beyond one-source-file exercises, using `make` becomes, if not essential, then highly advisable, not least because you can arrange for `make` to recompile only those things that need to be recompiled, but also to ensure that all the things that need to be recompiled are recompiled.  For small enough programs, simply recompiling everything is probably feasible with modern machines and compilers, but using `make` can save a lot of time (and pain and grief) on bigger projects.

Answer (score 2):

`make` simply gives commands to the compiler, such as `cc`. It automates building a project which has multiple files. To begin, you do not need to concern yourself with those details. Building a single file directly with `cc` is fine. In fact, you will understand how the compiler works so that you can get the most out of `make` when you eventually learn it.

Comment: So I'm guessing make it probably a more deliberate command when I have multiple files of some kind? Is it better for me to deliberately use cc for now?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with code-apprentice. I would just add that it is important to have a good understanding of different cc command line options before moving on to make. When you reach the point of a more complexe compilation project and the build process of your final binary becomes a pain, that's when you can transition to learning Make!